# Problema Firebase Xcode Compilacion

Tags: firebase, swift, xcode

Soy nuevo en Swift , estoy intentando conectar mi app con firebase , todo correcto hasta que se compila la aplicación y me muestra este mensaje.

2022-06-04 18:27:57.689039+0200 Quiz Oposiciones[1535:16666] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(153) Failed to log metrics

Este es el .swift que contiene la interfaz. Del siguiente código a la altura de .indices me salta un warning Non-constant range: not an integer range, no se si tiene que ver una cosa con la otra.

```
`import SwiftUI`

    `struct PreguntaRespuestaInterfaz: View {`
    `@Binding var verdadera : Int`
    `@Binding var falsa : Int`
    `@Binding var contestada : Int`
    `var set: String`
    `@StateObject var data = PreguntaViewModel()`
    
    
    `var body: some View {`
        
        `ZStack{`
            
            `if data.preguntas.isEmpty{`
                
                `ProgressView()`
        `}`
            `else{`
            
    `VStack {`
        `// Barra superior de progreso`
        
        `ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .center),`
               `content:{`
            
            `Capsule()`
                `.fill(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))`
                `.frame(height:6)`
            
            `Capsule()`
                `.fill(Color.green)`
                `.frame(width: 100, height: 6)`
        `})`
        `.padding()`
        
        `// Contador acierto y error`
        
        `HStack {`
            `Label(`
                `title:{ Text(verdadera == 0 ? "" : "\(verdadera)")`
                        `.font(.largeTitle)`
                        `.foregroundColor(.black)`
                `},`
                `icon: {Image(systemName: "checkmark")`
                        `.font(.largeTitle)`
                        `.foregroundColor(.green)`
                `})`
            
            `Spacer()`
            
            `Label(`
                `title:{ Text(falsa == 0 ? "" : "\(falsa)")`
                        `.font(.largeTitle)`
                        `.foregroundColor(.black)`
               ` },
                `icon: {Image(systemName: "xmark")`
                        `.font(.largeTitle)`
                        `.foregroundColor(.red)`
                `})`
       ` }`
        `.padding()`
        
           `//PreguntaView`
            
            `ZStack{`
                `ForEach(data.preguntas.reversed()***.indices***){ index in`
                    
                    `//View...`
                    `PreguntaView(pregunta: $data.preguntas[index], verdadera:`
```

`$verdadera, falsa: $falsa, contestada: $contestada)`

```
                `}`
            `}`
            `.padding()`
       ` }`
        `//fetching...`
        `.onAppear(perform: {`
            
            `data.getPreguntas(set: set)`
        
        `})`
    `}`
    
`}`
   ` }`
`}`
```

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Solo son mensajes o si ejecuta la app?

Comment: Se ejecuta la app el problema creo que va a ser lo que me comentas de la conexion